# vue-router with keep-alive can not cache pages in stack

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have some problems with vue-router:

There are two pages A and B, A->B means jump from A to B, this is fine. When one page occurs multiple time in single stack like A in A->B->A, I failed in trying to keep first A and B alive during back.

If I use `<keep-alive>` around `<router-view>`, the first A and the second A will share one component, I have to recreate the first A when click back button. And things will get worse without using `<keep-alive>`, I have to recreate every page in the stack.

So, I really need your help, thanks...